# Remove artifacts/noise from a depth analyzer

Tags: c++, image, depth, noise, scanning

Given two images and you can find the depth from scanning each row and differences, does anybody know how to remove noise?

for example, if the expected output is left and mine is right

http://sphotos-a.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-prn1/28905_10151279071291130_752649318_n.jpg

Does anybody have any coding tips to get rid of some of that noise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming this is caused by the hardware you are using.

You could average out the pixel colors based on neighboring pixels. Iterate through each column/row and adjust your color based on the surrounding colors. Do several passes on the entire image to give a greater effect.

This wouldn't get rid of the noise completely but it would give a softer image.

Additionally, if you are passing this through a graphics card you might consider writing a Shader. This would dramatically increase the speed.

Comment: I'm doing this purely through software.
We're given two images, at two different angles, and we scan it to find the best match between the pictures and we use that to find the depth.
I'm just using c++, but the idea to iterative through and adjust based on the surrounding colors is a good idea, I'm going to try that. Thank you.